# Java. Поиск по массиву

Tags: java

Прошу подсказки от опытных товарищей). Есть первая часть кода:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Shape[] arr = new Shape[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            Shape shape = new Shape();
            System.out.println("Введите значение стороны а фигуры № " + i);
            shape.a = scn.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Введите значение стороны b фигуры № " + i);
            shape.b = scn.nextInt();
            arr[i] = shape;
            shape.TypeDefinition();
            shape.getSquare();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i].print();
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].getSquare() == 0) {

            }
        }
        int max = arr[0].getSquare();
        int maxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].type.equals("Квадрат")) {
                if (max < arr[i].getSquare()) {
                    max = arr[i].getSquare();
                    maxIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Максимальная площадь квадрата из массива: " + arr[maxIndex].getSquare());
        System.out.println();

        int min = arr[0].getSquare();
        int minIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].type.equals("Прямоугольник")) {
                if (min > arr[i].getSquare()) {
                    min = arr[i].getSquare();
                    minIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Минимальная площадь прямоугольника из массива: " + arr[minIndex].getSquare());
    }
}
```

Требуется создать новый класс, который будет осуществлять поиск самого большого по площади квадрата и самого маленького по площади прямоугольника по массиву *arr*.
Кого не затруднит, расскажите как это сделать)

ps. Прошу прощения, что код не идеален, 2 месяца занимаюсь..

Comment: Вторая половина приведённого кода уже это делает. Можно разве что добавить вывод индекса элемента массива. Уточните вопрос. И в середине кода "пустой" цикле for. Зачем?

Comment: Т.е. вторую половину кода можно перенести в отдельный класс, а в классе main создать 2 объекта, в которых можно будет найти то, что требуется?

Answer (score 0):

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

    private final static int FIGURE_NUMBER = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final TreeMap<Integer,Boolean> shapes = new TreeMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < FIGURE_NUMBER; i++) {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            out.println("Введите значение стороны а фигуры № " + i);
            int a = scn.nextInt();
            out.println("Введите значение стороны b фигуры № " + i);
            int b = scn.nextInt();
            shapes.put(a*b, a==b);
        }

        shapes.descendingKeySet().stream()
                .filter(shape->shapes.get(shape)).findFirst()
                .ifPresent(val -> out.println("Максимальная площадь квадрата из массива: " + val));

        shapes.keySet().stream()
                .filter(shape->!shapes.get(shape)).findFirst()
                .ifPresent(val -> out.println("Минимальная площадь прямоугольника из массива: " + val));

    }

}
```

Ваш код слишком громоздкий и сложночитаемый. Задача достаточно тривиальная. Предлагаю более простое решение. Часть кода, отвечающую за пользовательский ввод, я практически не менял, кроме того, что заменил массив на коллекцию. Количество фигур можно менять переменной FIGURE_NUMBER (сейчас их 4, как и в Вашем примере, однако, в моем коде количество фигур значения не имеет). Попробуйте разобраться, если что-то непонятно - задавайте вопросы. Удачи!

Comment: Для каких целей вы, пихаете `Scanner` в цикл?

Comment: Это не я пихаю сканер в цикл, это автор вопроса. Я только отвечаю, каким образом можно решить задачу. Будет вопрос про сканер - отвечу про сканер.

Comment: Либо вам это кажется не странным, либо вы сами не понимаете, что может быть, если вы понимаете, знаете, то нужно отвечать на вопрос верным способом. ТС может не знать таких тонкостей, по этому допускает ошибку.

Comment: Я не совсем понял, что именно вы имеете в виду? То, что создание экземпляра класса сканер находится в цикле? Как по мне, то это совсем не критично по сравнению, к примеру, с отсутствием обработки исключений при пользовательском вводе. Хотя бы потому, что это по сути не может повлечь никаких негативных последствий для этого конкретного примера, в отличии от отсутствия обработчика исключений.